# Correct usage of subroutine in commodore basic 4.0?

Tags: arrays, printing, subroutine, basic, commodore

I have a subroutine which fills an array with "."s

In my main program I am trying to call this subroutine and then print the array; however, it doesn't seem to be working. I think I am incorrectly calling the subroutine?

This is my code:

subroutine:

```
1070 dim a$(x,x)
1080 for aa = 0 to x
1090 for bb = 0 to x
2000 a$(x,x)="."
2010 next
2020 next
```

main code:

```
10 input "please enter a number"; x
20 gosub 1070
30 for i = 1 to x
40 for j = 1 to x
50 print a$(i,j);
60 next
70 print
80 next
```

Nothing happens when run; but when I run it all in one program (not calling gosub) it works?

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In line #2000, I believe you want `a$(aa,bb)="."`, otherwise you're just hammering the same location with the initialization.

Also, and probably more important to your question, every `GOSUB` needs a `RETURN` to get back to the main line of execution.  In your case, that's probably line 2030.

Comment: If you print out the loop/array indices just before the assignment/print (between 40 and 50, 1090 and 2000), where do they end?  all at X?

Comment: With my recommended changes on a C128 emulator (is that close enough?), I get the expected square of periods but a `REDIM'D ARRAY ERROR IN 1070`, which (obviously) goes away if you add `END` on line 90.

Comment: @JohnSmith: Notice how you go from 0 to x in the subroutine, but go from 1 to x in the main program? In both cases, you should go from 0 to x-1; in BASIC, the first index is 0 and the last index is the number of elements minus one.

Comment: Actually, Commodore BASIC is a little weird.  The indices run from 0 to X.  Most languages are 0 to X-1, though.

Comment: @JohnC That's not just Commodore BASIC it's a BASIC thing in general to include the upper bound given in DIM, regardless if the array starts at index 0 or 1. There are BASIC dialects that start at index 1 and there are dialects where the programmer can choose if it is 0 or 1.